# iOS swift with tableview custom class

Tags: ios

I am creating iOS app with swift for the iPad. There is going to be table view for every view and I created a `UITableView` class but I cannot able to view any data. I have already linked the tableview inside other views to that custom class already.

```
import UIKit

class SideTable: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var TableItems = ["...", "Dashboard"]

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableItems[indexPath.row])! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping


    // let currentpagetitle = self.navigationItem.title?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let cellname = cell.reuseIdentifier?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

//        if (cellname == currentpagetitle)
//        {
//
//            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
//        }
//        

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the data source and delegate?
put in your viewwilllappear, for example (or viewDidLoad):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.tableview.datasource = self
  self.tableview.delegate = self
}
```

Or connect it if you are using Storyboard or Xib
Control + click over tableview and connect with owner, then selecte delegate and repeat for data source

If this is not the problem, maybe you have a problem with the definition of the cell. Change your dequeueCell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Use the same identifier if the cell are similar. Now you are using different names, you are using TableItems[indexPath.row] for each cell